# Sorting text on an image by relative font size

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I'm working on a project where we are trying to OCR old forms.  These forms are typeset, and the data is usually typed in.  The form has multiple font sizes and alignments.  Here is an example:
[image: original form image]

We have found that the varying font sizes and alignments yield poor OCR results.

We have taken a few images and manually reorganized them by font size.  A subset of the first sample, reorganized, may look like:
[image: image text organized by font size]

We've found that this reorganization yields significantly better OCR results.

I'm looking for techniques to automate this type of reorganization.  I've tried working with connected component/BLOB analysis to find elements by height.  This has generally given poor results due to the font size varying with the letter height because of ascenders and descenders of the letters.

Thanks for any insight into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Thinking aloud:**

This is indeed an uneasy problem as characters of the same face size don't all have the same height nor width (not counting the damaged and touching characters).

There is nothing you can do without some a priori knowledge of how printed fonts are made, and in particular the relative height/alignment of lowercase and uppercase. This said, characters in words are usually of the same face, face size and even casing and have a common baseline. In ordinary text, the baseline tends to extend along whole lines. But for short annotations or in filled forms, there is no rule you can rely on.

So a first challenge is to group characters in words, by telling white spaces from ordinary spacing. Then you can hypothesize that all characters in a word are of the same face size. You can also assume that the document contains a small number of different sizes (say up to five).

An option is to obtain the raw sizes of all characters, and to cluster them in a small number of clusters. Then you can verify the coherence of the sizes in a word by matching them to the clusters and checking homogeneity.

Notice that there is no perfect solution, and the last word can only be said by after recognition of the characters (!)